# BootStrap DatePicker popped twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

i applied a bootstrap datepicker on Text box, but whenever user select any Date or month. Another calendar popped out .

View:

```
<div class="input-append date" id="datepicker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Dob, new { @value = String.Empty, @readonly = true })
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

Model:

```
 [DisplayName(@"DOB")]
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
 public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Set The dateTime Calender for datepicker
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({

            todayHighlight: true,
        });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: How could I know that what's going on until you let me in into your secret source code vault

Comment: a code sample would help more

Comment: @ABrightWorker Please have a look i have update my Question.

Comment: Interesting... can you replicate in a fiddle?

Comment: @koala_dev  please use this [Implementation Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/D9Xav/3/)

Comment: @Andrew did you encounter the same behavior in the fiddle? because everything works fine when I test it in Chrome

Comment: @koala_dev no ,thats the problem. i cant replicate it on js Fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check , if you have defined a `custom editor Templates` for `DateTime`, and setting the class .`datepicker` there. its possible you are doing explicit duplicate initialization of calender control.

As you are using bootstrap ,`bootstrap-datepicker.js`  initializes the all nodes which has `.datepicker` class without explicit instruction.

Remove the explicit initialization in your function.