# Bootstrap Datetimepicker Display twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am getting the problem to display datetimepicker. i got the datetimepicker twice when i click id of shankar. I mentioned the screenshot below[image]

```
 <input class="form-control date"  data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii" data-link-field="dtp_input1" placeholder="select to validity" name="from_validity" type="text" id="shankar" value="">

 $('#shankar').datetimepicker();
```

Comment: Add your html structure

Comment: can you post your full script? you script working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/Lj9amwdk/1/

Comment: Share you complete code; are you loading data using ajax and then applying this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you:

```
<body>
<input class="form-control date"  data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii"    data-link-field="dtp_input1" placeholder="select to validity" name="from_validity" type="text" id="shankar" value="">
</body>
</html>
<script>
$("#shankar").click(function () {
    $("#shankar").datepicker('show').on('changeDate',function(ev){                 
     $('.datetimepicker').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: And how exactly will it help?

Comment: It's working .. But after selected the date and time ,it doesn't close the calender

Comment: I would like to add todayBtn:1 in this code for visible today button in datetimepicker. How to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Please check , if you have defined a `custom editor Templates` for `DateTime`, and setting the class .`datepicker` there. its possible you are doing explicit duplicate initialization of calender control.

As you are using bootstrap ,`bootstrap-datepicker.js`  initializes the all nodes which has `.datepicker` class without explicit instruction.

Remove the explicit initialization in your function.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875691/bootstrap-datepicker-poped-twice)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.dpdatetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    startDate: new Date(start_date),
    todayBtn: "linked",
    orientation: "bottom auto",
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "5",
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true
        });
},1000);
```

Comment: Can you please give some explaination